# Getting starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe''

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, windows-10

by running  `gradlew run` on Window 10 The following error is displayed in the terminal :

```
> Task :storage:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':storage:run'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Any suggestion is  welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure what just happened; but for me, working in a spring-boot project, changing *Shorten command line* option in Run/Debug Configurations to *JAR manifest* from *none* solved the issue.

[image: Shorten command line in Run/Debug Configurations]